# How can I get a JSON response from Github's REST API?

Tags: rest, github, github-api

I'm trying to use [this guide](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) to get a list of all issues from a repository. For example, let's look at [the `facebook/react` repository](https://github.com/facebook/react/).

When I do a GET request to `https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/` it just returns the web page, but what I want is a JSON with all the issues.

How can I get a JSON response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the API's [root endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/#root-endpoint), on the `api` subdomain:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/issues
            ^^^^
```